# Shutting Down VM Android Studio

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using **Exoplayer** and Google media framework library to develop an android app.

It's basically a video player with some ads. My app always crashes and the Logcat msg displays Shutting down VM and also some msgs like this-

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class 
   java.lang.Class<com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.
     exoplayerextensions.ObservablePlayerControl>
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class 
   java.lang.Class<com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.
     exoplayerextensions.ExoplayerWrapper
```

I am getting `fullScreenCallback` as `null`.

Is this the reason why my app is crashing.

Comment: How about some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Rejecting+re-init+on+previously-failed+class+java.lang.Class

Comment: I am not getting any errors or any exceptions, only app crahes

Comment: and the above msg is displayed as warning

Comment: Can you paste code which you might think is causing trouble?

Comment: share crash info please